# How to get object value in foreach

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program, which can disable and re-enable the network adapter after 10 sec.
It works if I don't use the "IF" statement. But I want to use a timeout (Thread.Sleep() )

How can I get the object value and compare it?

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection adapters = searcher.Get();


    // enumerate all network adapters
    foreach (ManagementObject adapter in adapters)
    {
        adapter.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
        if (adapter. = )  // ==> Here is my problem, how can i get if adapter
                          //     is enabled or disabled
        { }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Something like `adapter["NetEnabled"]` should work to retrieve the property.

Comment: You should check whether `NetConnectionStatus == 0` before calling `Enable`. Then make a new query and check the `NetConnectionStatus` of the adapters you're interested in, to verify whether the status has changed (after a timeout). Are you sure you want to enable all NetworkAdapters that have a non-null `NetConnectionId`? That's just a description string...